# If is correct password, then redirect

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem. I need to do that if a user writes a correct password, he will be redirected to another page. What's wrong with this? :/
Thanks for answers!

```
  <section>
    <input type="password" id="heslo" name="heslo">
    <button id="ok">OK</button>
    <script>
        var pass = document.getElementById("heslo");
        var pass1 = "CorrectPassword";
        var ok = document.getElementById("ok");
        if (ok.onClick) {
            if (pass === pass1) {
                document.Write('<a href="Rozvrh.html"></a>');
            }
        }
    </script>
</section>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Comment: I hope this is just for learning and you aren't actually intending to store the password client-side 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add function to your button and compare value of `pass` using `pass.value`. Because when you use `pass` you get refer to html-element and trying to compare it with the string. And for redirect you can use `window.location.href =` 
Tryout this:

```html
  <section>
    <input type="password" id="heslo" name="heslo">
    <button id="ok">OK</button>
    <script>
        var pass1 = "CorrectPassword";
        var ok = document.getElementById("ok");
        ok.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
        var pass = document.getElementById("heslo");
        if(pass.value === pass1) {
            window.location.href = 'Rozvrh.html';
        }
        else alert('Passwords do not match');
        })
    </script>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the value of the input right now you have just targeted that input

```
var pass = document.getElementById("heslo");
```

you need to get the value of this input try this

```
var pass = document.getElementById("heslo").value;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need use `window.location.href = url` to redirect to your URL.

Also your code can not run because typo `onClick` and wrong event handler, and did not get value for `pass` element.

I update your code to runable as

```
var ok = document.getElementById("ok");
ok.onclick = function() {
    var pass = document.getElementById("heslo");
    var pass1 = "CorrectPassword";

    if (pass.value === pass1) {
        window.location.href = "Rozvrh.html";
    } else {
        alert('wrong pass');
    }
}
```

```js
var ok = document.getElementById("ok");
ok.onclick = function() {
    var pass = document.getElementById("heslo");
    var pass1 = "CorrectPassword";

    if (pass.value === pass1) {
        window.location.href = "Rozvrh.html";
    } else {
        alert('wrong pass');
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="password" id="heslo" name="heslo">
 <button id="ok">OK</button>
```